# Vuetify - Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'undefined' instead

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a form with datepicker, the validation is working as intended but I keep getting an error message in the browser's console, "Rules should return a string or boolean, received 'undefined' instead" I just want to get rid of it, but I'm not sure where and at what moment the rule it is returning undefined.

Also the "future" rule is always returning false for some reason

```html
<template>
<div>
    <v-container>
        <v-card>
            <div class="container">
                <v-form ref="form" v-model="isValid">
                    <v-row>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6">
                            <v-menu ref="menu" v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" :return-value.sync="date" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="290px">
                                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                                    <v-text-field v-model="route.departure" label="Departure" color="black" readonly v-on="on" :rules="[rules.required, rules.future]"></v-text-field>
                                </template>
                                <v-date-picker v-model="route.departure" no-title scrollable color="amber lighten-2">
                                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                    <v-btn color="red accent-3" class="black-text" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                                    <v-btn color="yellow" class="black-text" @click="$refs.menu.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
                                </v-date-picker>
                            </v-menu>
                        </v-col>

                        <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6">
                            <v-menu ref="menu_2" v-model="menu_2" :close-on-content-click="false" :return-value.sync="date" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="290px">
                                <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                                    <v-text-field v-model="route.arrival" label="Arrival" color="black" :rules="[rules.required, rules.today, rules.future]" readonly v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                                </template>
                                <v-date-picker v-model="route.arrival" no-title scrollable color="amber lighten-2">
                                    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                    <v-btn color="red accent-3" class="black-text" @click="menu_2 = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                                    <v-btn color="yellow" class="black-text" @click="$refs.menu_2.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
                                </v-date-picker>
                            </v-menu>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-row>
                </v-form>
            </div>

        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isValid: true,
            date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
            menu: false,
            menu_2: false,
            route: {
                departure: '',
                arrival: '',
            },



            rules: {
                required: value => !!value || 'Required.',
                arrival: value => {
                    return (new Date(this.route.departure) < new Date(this.route.arrival) || 'Arrival date must be after the Departure date');
                },
                future: value => {
                    return (new Date() <= new Date(this.route.departure) && (new Date() <= new Date(this.route.arrival))) || "Date must be today's date or after"
                }

            }
        }
    },




}
</script>
```

Comment: where are you updating `departure` and `arrival` fields?

Comment: from the `v-text-field` in each datepicker, those fields have as v-model the `departure` and `arrival` fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue comes from `:rules="[rules.required, rules.today, rules.future]"` since `today` rule is **undefined** and modify `future` and `arrival` by adding the `value` as parameter of the date constructor :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      isValid: true,
      date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      menu: false,
      menu_2: false,
      route: {
        departure: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
        arrival: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
      },



      rules: {
        required: value => !!value || 'Required.',
        arrival: value => {
          return (new Date(value) < new Date(this.route.arrival) || 'Arrival date must be after the Departure date');
        },
        future: value => {
          return  (new Date() <= new Date(this.route.departure) && (new Date() <= new Date(value))) || "Date must be today's date or after"
        }

      }
    }
  },



})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <v-card>
          <div class="container">
            <v-form ref="form" v-model="isValid">
              <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6">
                  <v-menu ref="menu" v-model="menu" :close-on-content-click="false" :return-value.sync="date" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="290px">
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                                    <v-text-field v-model="route.departure" label="Departure" color="black" readonly v-on="on" :rules="[rules.required, rules.future]"></v-text-field>
                                </template>
                    <v-date-picker v-model="route.departure" no-title scrollable color="amber lighten-2">
                      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      <v-btn color="red accent-3" class="black-text" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                      <v-btn color="yellow" class="black-text" @click="$refs.menu.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
                    </v-date-picker>
                  </v-menu>
                </v-col>

                <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="6">
                  <v-menu ref="menu_2" v-model="menu_2" :close-on-content-click="false" :return-value.sync="date" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="290px">
                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                                    <v-text-field v-model="route.arrival" label="Arrival" color="black" :rules="[rules.required, rules.future]" readonly v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                                </template>
                    <v-date-picker v-model="route.arrival" no-title scrollable color="amber lighten-2">
                      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                      <v-btn color="red accent-3" class="black-text" @click="menu_2 = false">Cancel</v-btn>
                      <v-btn color="yellow" class="black-text" @click="$refs.menu_2.save(date)">OK</v-btn>
                    </v-date-picker>
                  </v-menu>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
            </v-form>
          </div>

        </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```